Removing bi-grams after tokenization for TfidfVectorizer
I'm attempting to remove bi-grams that are created by TfidfVectorizer.  I'm using text.TfidfVectorizer so that I can use my own preprocessor function.
Test strings and preprocessor function:
doc2 = ['this is a test past performance here is another that has aa aa adding builing cat dog horse hurricane', 
        'another that has aa aa and start date and hurricane hitting south carolina']

def remove_bigrams(doc):
    gram_2 = ['past performance', 'start date', 'aa aa']
    res = []
    for record in doc:
        the_string = record
        for phrase in gram_2:
            the_string = the_string.replace(phrase, "")
        res.append(the_string)
    return res

remove_bigrams(doc2)

My TfidfVectorizer instantiation and fit_transform:
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS as stop_words
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text

custom_stop_words = [i for i in stop_words]

vec = text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=custom_stop_words,
                           analyzer='word',
                           ngram_range=(2, 2),
                           preprocessor=remove_bigrams,
                          )

features = vec.fit_transform(doc2)

Here is my error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [49], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 #t3_cv = CountVectorizer(t2, stop_words = stop_words)
      4 vec = text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=custom_stop_words, analyzer='word', ngram_range = (2,2), preprocessor = remove_bigrams)
----> 5 features = vec.fit_transform(doc2)

File c:\Development_Solutions\Sandbox\SBVE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py:2079, in TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   2072 self._check_params()
   2073 self._tfidf = TfidfTransformer(
   2074     norm=self.norm,
   2075     use_idf=self.use_idf,
   2076     smooth_idf=self.smooth_idf,
   2077     sublinear_tf=self.sublinear_tf,
   2078 )
-> 2079 X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   2080 self._tfidf.fit(X)
   2081 # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so
   2082 # we set copy to False

File c:\Development_Solutions\Sandbox\SBVE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py:1338, in CountVectorizer.fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1330             warnings.warn(
   1331                 "Upper case characters found in"
   1332                 " vocabulary while 'lowercase'"
   1333                 " is True. These entries will not"
   1334                 " be matched with any documents"
   1335             )
   1336             break
-> 1338 vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1340 if self.binary:
   1341     X.data.fill(1)

File c:\Development_Solutions\Sandbox\SBVE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py:1209, in CountVectorizer._count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1207 for doc in raw_documents:
   1208     feature_counter = {}
-> 1209     for feature in analyze(doc):
   1210         try:
   1211             feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

File c:\Development_Solutions\Sandbox\SBVE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py:113, in _analyze(doc, analyzer, tokenizer, ngrams, preprocessor, decoder, stop_words)
    111     doc = preprocessor(doc)
    112 if tokenizer is not None:
--> 113     doc = tokenizer(doc)
    114 if ngrams is not None:
    115     if stop_words is not None:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

How to resolve it?

The preprocessor should handle documents, not the whole corpus. (The clues are the "expected string" in the error, and the fact that the TfidfVectorizer docs refer to "the preprocessing (string transformation) stage". The docs could definitely be clearer.)
This should fix it:
def remove_bigrams(doc: str) -> str:
    """Remove certain bi-grams from a document."""
    gram_2 = ['past performance', 'start date', 'aa aa']
    for phrase in gram_2:
        doc = doc.replace(phrase, "")
    return doc


Yes!  That worked!  Thank you Matt.  What this piece of information in the documentation somewhere for TfidfVectorizer?  Specifically, the preprocessor handling documents and not the whole corpus?  I thought I was implementing that with the first for loop, but I guess it wasn't the way the preprocessor required the data.

I updated the answer with some reasoning / evidence.
